# Checking every path when evaluating limit

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Evaluate limit or show that it does not exist.

So my main question is, how can we check that the limit goes to every path? Am I just plugging in $(x,0)$ and $(0,y)$ and then seeing if they are the same? If they are not the same, then can I assume that the limit does not exist?

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{3x^2-4y^2}{6x^2+5y^2}$$

Comment: Well what did you try?

Comment: hi @user474986 thanks for your response. I corrected my question. My main issue is, how can I check every path and what does it mean if I get different results?

Comment: If the limit exists, then it must be same along every path. Therefore to show that limit doesn't exist, choose two paths which give distinct limits.

Comment: Thank you @user474986. I think I am clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you evaluate a limit, you want it to have the same limit no matter what "path" you take.

Take $(x, y) = (x, 0) \to (0, 0)$

$$\lim_{(x,y)=(x,0)\to (0,0)}\frac{3x^2}{6x^2}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Take $(x, y) = (0, y) \to (0, 0)$

$$\lim_{(x,y)=(0,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{-4y^2}{5y^2}=\frac{-4}{5}$$

Since the limits using different paths are different, the final limit doesn't exist

(Basically extending the "left-right limit" from single-varible calculus)

Comment: Hi @Gareth Ma , thank you for your response. So i can assume that if i plug in values where y goes to zero, and then values for x goes to zero, if the result is different then the limit does not exist, correct?

Comment: Yes. Or more generally, for any path. For example if you take (x, y) = (t, t) here, the limit evaluates to (3-4)/(6+5)=-1/11 as well.

Comment: Dou you mean _trajectory_?

Comment: Is that what it's called? Sorry i don't know haha

Comment: Please, be responsible and check your MathJax formatting before posting an answer. (:

Comment: Hi @GarethMa So in this example above, you simply got rid of x and y (made them 0) and the result was -1/11. Meaning, if the result was 0, the limit would exist?

Comment: Not that when it's 0, but rather when it matches the other paths' limit.

Comment: @oldcsstudent Is it clear? would you mind accepting the solution, it would hhelp

Comment: Thank you - I am clear now. I will accept. how can I earn back some of those lost points as I see that my questions is -2 now.

Comment: @oldcsstudent helped :)

Comment: Thank you so much @GarethMa for helping me understand